# Excluding files/folders from VSTS publish

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are using the new VSO/VSTS style build within TFS on premise, 2015 Update 1 as of yesterday.

During the publish build artifacts stage we want to copy all the files/folders from a root bar 2 sub folders.

ie:

```
$\somefilestopublish1\...
$\somefilestopublish2\...
$\somefilestoexclude1\...
$\somefilestoexclude2\...
```

Currently I have `**\*` as the contents argument which obviously will publish everything.  I have tried appending `;-:<exclude_pattern>` as suggested by a Google search but that just stopped all output and resulted in an empty folder.

Is there a way to use the minimatch expression to exclude folders or will I need to swap to explicitly selecting the folders to publish instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Minimatch use "!" to exclude the given pattern. You could specify it with following format:

```
!(somefilestoexclude1|somefilestoexclude2)
```

Following is the example:
With !(bin|obj), "bin" folder and "obj" folder under "WindowsFormsApplication1" folder are not copied to artifact.
[image]

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm till struggling with this:

I have : `!(_build|$tf)/*` but I'm still coping the $tf and _build folders into my drop.

Comment: @themaninthesuitcase I just create a sample and add the screenshot in the answer, please refer to it for details.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT How would this work for ignoring certain file types. Like .pdb and .xml?

Comment: @Thomas Refer to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/utility/copy-files#ExamplesCopyexecutablesandareadmefile

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Thank you! :)

Comment: Using **\!($tf) to copy everything except the $tf folder doesn't work in tfs2017.1.

Answer (score 1):

!/$tf/** works for me.  I've opted to shorten that to !/$*/**

http://www.globtester.com/ helped.  The $ symbol doesn't have to be escaped despite conflicting guidance on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx.

Comment: You don't need to @ping the OP.  He'll find out there's an answer anyway (and I think it only works from comments).

Comment: @Teepeemm I intended to add a comment, but lack the reputation.

Comment: @piet.t I don't follow your point.  The essential part of the answer is that /!($tf)/** worked for me.  The 2 links augment (but are not essential to) the answer.  That said, as it turns out, /!($tf)/** isn't including files in the root folder so I'm still searching for a better minimatch pattern.

Comment: !/$tf/** is the best solution I've found, and I've opted to shorten that to: !/$*/**

Comment: @JasonVercellone Do you have to combine this with something else to copy everything except the $tf folder?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to collect all the ***.nupkg** files in your solution (for instance the ones you create during build) and copy them to another folder, but you want to ***exclude*** the ones you get through the package restore, you need to specify the following:

`**\*.nupkg
!packages\**`

It's important to specify them in this order. Placing the exclusion on the packages folder on top, will result in the Copy task copying all the *.nupkg files.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for folder try this !**\Uploads***
For file **!(Web.config)

Above example is for excluding a folder and file available in same folder path.

Answer (score 0):

On TFS 2017 Update 1 if you are using the Copy Files task and you want to copy all files from the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) but exclude the $tf folder what I found to work was the following.

In the Contents text box enter the following two lines.

```
**\*
!$tf\**
```

[This post on social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb22c23e-cb44-44d2-8170-ba5609e9a688/need-help-excluding-the-tf-folder-and-sub-items?forum=TFService) is what helped me figure this out.