# Excluding an entire folder / contents from 'Copy Files' step in TFS 2017 build definition

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm struggling with getting a TFS build definition to exclude an entire folder and all of its contents from a "Copy Files" step, as shown here:
[image]

Here's essentially what I'm trying to do:

Copy **everything** *except* a folder named 'node_modules' from:

```
\\Test\Source
```

to:

```
\\Test\Destination
```

The path of the folder I need to **exclude** is:

```
\\Test\Source\AppsJs\v3\node_modules
```

I can easily exclude *files* using the same pattern as I have above, but I can't figure out how to exclude the entire *folder*.

I've also seen some suggesting using `-:` as well, but I haven't been able to get that to work.

I've tried looking at the "Copy Files" documentation [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files#ExamplesCopyexecutablesandareadmefile), and read some more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041949/excluding-files-folders-from-vsts-publish#) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201825/tfs-drop-exclude-obj-folder-using-minimatch-pattern), but I'm still just missing something.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should set the contents with two lines as:

```
**\**
!AppsJs\v3\node_modules\**
```

Comment: Ahh! That got me on the right track at least, and I got it to totally exclude the `node_modules` folder by changing what you had, `\node_modules\*.*`, to `\node_modules\**`. Since I'm new here, should I still mark as answer even though it was a bit different, or can you edit your answer slightly to match what fixed it? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reminder. I updated my answer just now.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for a solution in 2020, here is what I did:

```
**/*
!.git/**
!node_modules/**
```